# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (dateofbirth) specified for User

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, debugging

Hi im trying to add a DOB field to my django project but I keep getting this error but i cant find where to find it

```
 File "C:\Users\Ugur\Documents\Reply\Replyproject\accounts\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Ugur\Documents\Reply\Replyproject\accounts\views.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .forms import CreateUserForm
  File "C:\Users\Ugur\Documents\Reply\Replyproject\accounts\forms.py", line 9, in <module>
    class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "C:\Users\Ugur\Anaconda3\envs\ECS639U\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 276, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (dateofbirth) specified for User
```

My Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms




class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'dateofbirth']
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



# Create your views here.
from .models import *
from .forms import CreateUserForm

def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)

                return redirect('/login')
            

        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password =request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/login')


@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    dateofbirth= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    creditcard = models.CharField(max_length=16, null = True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The console I cant understand where the issue is located to change to add the label onto the register area any help is fully thank have a good afternoon :)

Comment: User field are mentioned here you may choose from them http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth

Comment: Im wondering so you cant credit custom fields for user fields?

Comment: You can but you have not.

Comment: No field named dateofbirth in User model mentioned in CreateUserForm..

Comment: I had similar error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (memberscreated_by) specified for Project` because I forgot to put comma between form fields eg   `'members'   'created_by',` which should have been `'members',  'created_by',`

Answer (score 2):

In your forms, you specified a field for Modal = User, but your Class called Customer. When you say **modal = User** Django tries to use own User Modal which does not have dateofbirth field.

Comment: So what is the work around?
How to use dateofbirth?
with model = User?